# php REMOTE_USER variable

Tags: php, apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04, single-sign-on, mediawiki

I am trying to setup mediawiki with SSO. I was able to set up authentification with domain, but I cannot setup SSO.
For some reason, $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'] variable is not set.
I looked into some anwsers in SO, but has no luck solving my issue. 
I have also configured basic apache auth, but still no luck with getting remote user.

apache.conf:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "some_auth"
    AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthUserFile /path/to/file
    Satisfy Any
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

Comment: By `apache.conf`, do you mean `httpd.conf` or is `apache.conf` something specific to mediawiki?

Comment: Yes, I mean httpd.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, seems that `Satisfy Any` was the reason, that REMOTE_USER was absent.